# I wanna make a form in HTML to accept student ID and score from input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

and this is the criteria :

- Create a form in HTML to accept student ID and score from input
- LA button to do operation
- When the button is clicked, it will check the score validity first (numbers, range 0 - 100) and will alert user if the score is invalid
- If the score is valid, then convert to letter score and show it based on these criteria
  a. If score is A or A-, the Student ID, Letter and Score will be GREEN
  b. If score is B+, B, or B-, the Student ID, Letter and Score will be BLUE
  c. If score is C+ or C, the Student ID, Letter and Score will be ORANGE
  d. If score is D or E, the Student ID, Letter and Score will be RED
- Everytime a valid score is submitted and shown, the input will be empty and accept new input
  AND WILL ADD INTO NEW LINE

i hopefull for someone  can helping me for solve this problem for my assignment in my college cause i'm newbie in programming classs thankyouuu

Comment: I'll do this for you, but I'll leave gaps so you can learn. Send me sample grades. for example 0-30 = red = DD

Comment: where is your code, what have you tried? put your code in a snippet so we can edit it to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.